# LocalStorage table columns sort

Tags: javascript, dom, local-storage

I use this [table-dragger plugin](https://github.com/sindu12jun/table-dragger).

I want save sorted data table on localStorage, when then user reloads the page I want to save the ordered table for him.

I have code:

```
var el = document.getElementById('table');
var dragger = tableDragger(el, {
  mode: 'column',
  dragHandler: '.handle',
  onlyBody: true,
  animation: 300
});

dragger.on('drop',function(from, to){
  // Setting the Value.
  localStorage.setItem("keyName", "value"); // Syntax
  localStorage.setItem("table_layout", table_layout); // by variable
  localStorage.setItem("table_layout", "from to?"); // by value

   // Get the value.
   localStorage.getItem("table_layout");

   // Clear one item.
   localStorage.removeItem("table_layout");

   // Clear all items.
   localStorage.clear();
});
```

I don't know how to save the ordered data table correctly. When I reload the page, all my changes lost.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're trying to do. For instance, you save items to `localStorage`, but then you call `clear`, which removes them all, as your comment states. If you clear all items from `localStorage`, they'll not be there when you reload...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: What code do you have to set the changes when the page reloads?